# Non Primary Key but Auto Incrementing id for Eloquent ORM Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

So I've read the Laravel documentation on Eloquent and how it assumes that the table has a primaryKey called id.

I currently have a `id` field in the table that is `auto-incrementing` however, it is not a `primary key`. I have a `composite primary key` which eloquent doesn't fully support. This is not a huge issue for me. I don't mind working with the `id` field that is auto-incrementing.

I am just wondering if `Eloquent` will be able to work with `id` key even though it is not a `primary key`, but a `auto incrementing` one.

Answer (score 0):

You may use any custom primary key in your `table` but only thing you need to explicitly declare the `PK` in the model, for example:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'custom_pk';
```

It'll work without any problem even when there is an `id` (non primary key) field in the table.

Comment: Can I use a non-primary-key `id` which is auto incrementing in Eloquent?

Comment: [Check this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35449/how-to-use-2-auto-increment-columns-in-mysql-phpmyadmin).

Comment: How does that question relate? (If you could point me to the specific answer)

Comment: That answer (second one) states everything very clearly so i pointed you to that answer, anyways, `It is only available for the MyISAM Storage Engine` and it's related to the `database`, if you specify a custom `PK` explicitly in your model then `Eloquent` would work. Auto-incremental field increases within the database not externally by `Eloquent`. Each time a new record inserted, the `AI` fields increases inside `database` by the `database` engine.